# What do you as parameters to external functions in solidity that take struct as parameters?

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3.py

There's a function in solidity Im looking at which takes the custom datatype

```
DecreaseLiquidityParams as input. 
    function decreaseLiquidity(DecreaseLiquidityParams calldata params)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint256 amount0, uint256 amount1);
```

DecreaseLiquidityParams id defined in another file as:

```
struct DecreaseLiquidityParams {
    uint256 tokenId;
    uint128 liquidity;
    uint256 amount0Min;
    uint256 amount1Min;
    uint256 deadline;
}
```

So If I'm calling this function through web3 on python, do I pass the parameters in individually or as a dictionary? like this:

```
contract.functions.DecreaseLiquidity(12345,100,100,100,100).buildTransaction(..)
```

Answer (score 4):

You would just use a JSON format for that param. In web3js, the method would accept a JSON object as follows:

```js
contract.decreaseLiquidity({ tokenId: 12345, liquidity: 100, amount0Min: 100, amount1Min: 100, deadline: 100}).send()
```

In web3py, the method would accept the param as a dictionary as follows:

```py
contract.decreaseLiquidity({ "tokenId": 12345, "liquidity": 100, "amount0Min": 100, "amount1Min": 100, "deadline": 100}).transact()
```